# Seed generator best and safe?

Tags: security, tangle, seed

Which is the best seed generator and is there an official one 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**NEVER USE A WEB SOLUTION**

There are many solutions, but I think the following are common. It's just a general way of generating random strings. I don't recommend to use any web-solution. It's probably scam, because it's like generating your password at website. I don't think that anyone would do this. So just use the command line for it.

Windows:

```
@Echo Off
:: Generates semi-random alphanumeric character, upper/lower case A-z and 0-9
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set _Alphanumeric=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
[COLOR=DarkRed]Set _count=0
:_loop
Set /a _count+=1[/COLOR]
SET _RND=%Random%
:: Use (Number of characters-1) as the [COLOR=Blue]mod operand[/COLOR]. So for just 26 letters use 25 instead of 61
Set /A _RND=_RND%%[COLOR=Blue]61[/COLOR]
SET _rndalphanum=!_Alphanumeric:~%_RND%,1!
Echo Random character is !_rndalphanum!
[COLOR=DarkRed]If !_count! leq 21 goto _loop
[/COLOR]
```

source: https://forums.techguy.org/threads/random-numbers-and-letters.803268/

Linux:

```
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1
```

source: https://gist.github.com/earthgecko/3089509

You just need to modify it, so it only contains a-z, A-Z and 9

Comment: **NEVER USE A WEB SOLUTION** 

That's the way a lot of users lost their IOTA. Always go with a download from github or run a snippet like above

Comment: Added it also as bold. It's important to notice. :)

Comment: %random% is not cryptographically secure. Indeed, it uses the timestamp, which opens a huge gaping security hole, and makes the security absolutely dismal. **DO NOT USE**

Comment: @eukaryote Any better solution for windows user?

Answer (score 0):

Dice method seems to me to be the safest. If you're super paranoid about malware or viruses on your machine, it's defo worth a shot.

https://www.reddit.com/r/Iota/comments/7hos4t/secure_dice_roll_seed_generator_template/

However, you will still have an issue with entering the key into the wallet, you could well have a keylogger.

Best to use a clean OS if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the options posted [here](https://kb.helloiota.com/KnowledgebaseArticle50005.aspx).

IE, For Linux:

> cat /dev/urandom |tr -dc A-Z9|head -c${1:-81}

Note: Do NOT use Command Prompt or Powershell to generate your seed. They are known to not be truly random, and hackers are exploiting the use of these for generating seeds that have a higher liklihood of being generated.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux and Mac you can use the Terminal one-liner command:

- Linux:

  ```
  cat /dev/urandom |tr -dc A-Z9|head -c${1:-81}
  ```
- Mac:

  ```
  cat /dev/urandom |LC_ALL=C tr -dc 'A-Z9' | fold -w 81 | head -n 1
  ```

For Windows there is no one-liner solution. Instead you can use Python or KeePass

- If you have Python installed on your OS system (type into the python console):

  ```
  from random import SystemRandom 
  alphabet = u'9ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' 
  generator = SystemRandom() 
  print(u''.join(generator.choice(alphabet) for _ in range(81)))
  ```
- Use KeePass to generate a 81 char seed containing A-Z and additional nines (see https://ukcryptocurrency.com/iota/how-to-make-an-iota-seed/). You can then decide to leave your seed in KeePass or not.

In general I would not trust web application or so called online seed generators. They could be compromised.

Comment: Hi thanks for this but if we still go to link still don’t work offline as in previous posts it says online is not safe.is this is safe to use

Answer (score 0):

I would say to use any PRNG (Pseudo random number generator) you trust. Urandom is ok I guess, but I still prefer https://www.random.org/ to get some bits or characters.

Remember that there are a lot of keys: 27<sup>81</sup>, it's hard to forge collision so don't worry too much about it.